# Promise chaining. Wait for last promise to resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I have 2 functions:

```
    getDocument: function(title){

    var defer = $q.defer();

    $timeout(function(){

        defer.resolve(true);            
        console.log(1);

    },2000);

    return defer.promise;
},

anotherFunc : function(){

    var defer = $q.defer();

    console.log(2);
    defer.resolve(document);

    return defer.promise;

}
```

and a call:

```
    when('/entry/:title', {templateUrl: 'partials/views/entry.php', controller: 'entryCtrl',resolve: {

    document: function($q,$route,$log,document){

        var defer = $q.defer();

        document.getDocument()
            .then(document.anotherFunc());               

        return defer.promise;
    }
}}).
```

Although i have applied a timeout to `getDocument()`, `anotherFunc()` get's called, even when the promise has not been resolved yet.

Why is this?

How can i avoid this behaviour?

Comment: You have some typos, document.getDocument().then(document.anotherFunc);

You are actually calling document.anotherFunc in your code, you are not passing it as an argument to the then function.

Comment: @TestersGonnaTest
Thank you, fixed. This was not part of the real code, just an issue due to the refactoring for SO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> anotherFunc() get's called, even when the promise has not been resolved yet.

Because you have *called* it:

```
… document.anotherFunc() …
                      ^^
```

Instead, you want to pass a function into `then()` that will get called when the promise resolves:

```
….then(document.anotherFunc)

// or, more explicit and preserving 'this':
….then(function(promiseResult) {
    document.anotherFunc();
})
```